# How to add multiple arguments to my custom template filter in a django template?

Tags: python, django, replace, django-templates, django-template-filters

Here's my custom filter:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def replace(value, cherche, remplacement):
    return value.replace(cherche, remplacement)
```

And, here are the ways I tried using it in my template file that resulted in an error:

```
{{ attr.name|replace:"_"," " }}
{{ attr.name|replace:"_" " " }}
{{ attr.name|replace:"_":" " }}
{{ attr.name|replace:"cherche='_', remplacement=' '" }}
```

I looked into [django's docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) and [book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter10/) but only found example using a single argument... is it even possible?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

It is possible and fairly simple.

Django only allows one argument to your filter, but there's no reason you can't put all your arguments into a single string using a comma to separate them.

So for example, if you want a filter that checks if variable X is in the list [1,2,3,4] you will want a template filter that looks like this:

```
{% if X|is_in:"1,2,3,4" %}
```

Now we can create your templatetag like this:

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

def is_in(var, args):
    if args is None:
        return False
    arg_list = [arg.strip() for arg in args.split(',')]
    return var in arg_list

register.filter(is_in)
```

The line that creates arg_list is a generator expression that splits the args string on all the commas and calls .strip() to remove any leading and trailing spaces.

If, for example, the 3rd argument is an int then just do:

```
arg_list[2] = int(arg_list[2])
```

Or if all of them are ints do:

```
arg_list = [int(arg) for arg in args.split(',')]
```

EDIT: now to specifically answer your question by using key,value pairs as parameters, you can use the same class Django uses to parse query strings out of URL's, which then also has the benefit of handling character encoding properly according to your settings.py.

So, as with query strings, each parameter is separated by '&':

```
{{ attr.name|replace:"cherche=_&remplacement= " }}
```

Then your replace function will now look like this:

```
from django import template
from django.http import QueryDict

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def replace(value, args):
    qs = QueryDict(args)
    if qs.has_key('cherche') and qs.has_key('remplacement'):
        return value.replace(qs['cherche'], qs['remplacement'])
    else:
        return value
```

You could speed this up some at the risk of doing some incorrect replacements:

```
qs = QueryDict(args)
return value.replace(qs.get('cherche',''), qs.get('remplacement',''))
```

Comment: Ifthe values for these are in variables how to implement this...?

Comment: This seemed helpful, but I couldn't get it to work with variables being passed. To do so, I had use a `tag` or `simple_tag` - which allows for multiple variables, even named variables to be passed.

Comment: I'm way from the future, but seems to me a tag would be a better solution than essentially writing a parser in the filter.

Answer (score 36):

**It is more simple than you think** 
You can use ***simple_tag*** for this.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def multiple_args_tag(a, b, c, d):
   #do your stuff
   return
```

**In Template**:

```
{% multiple_args_tag 'arg1' 'arg2' 'arg3' 'arg4' %}
```

> NOTE: Don't forget to re-run the server.

Comment: Thanks! When `safe` is needed, you can use it as follows: `{% multiple_args_tag 'arg1' 'arg2' 'arg3' 'arg4' as my_var_name %}` followed by `{{ my_var_name|safe }}`

Answer (score 31):

It's easy like this.

```
@register.filter(name='one_more')
def one_more(_1, _2):
    return _1, _2

def your_filter(_1_2, _3)
    _1, _2 = _1_2
    print "now you have three arguments, enjoy"

{{ _1|one_more:_2|your_filter:_3 }}
```

Comment: Really great thank you for this solution. I have upgraded it a little so you can chain different lengths of parameters. https://gist.github.com/BrnoPCmaniak/e9552294b3059461f940a47143f58811

Comment: This should be correct answer ! It's a beautiful python solution (maybe not the best django solution, see @dragonroot answer)

Comment: This is quite a solution. Thanks helped a lot !! :)

Comment: Is working, thank you. No need to add name to @register.filter() and your_filter needs register.filter() too.

Answer (score 21):

Instead of a filter, register your tag as a simple tag. Those can take multiple arguments. The syntax for invoking it will be a little bit different, but that's just syntactic sugar changing.

Comment: This was the correct answer for my issue. In order to pass a template variable into this function, I had to use a `simple_tag`.

Comment: This is a good solution. It is definitely worth checking out the django docs for the simple tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags

Comment: This is what makes the most sense to me. Tags are more powerful and complex than filters, thus if your problem is more complex seems like a better approach than trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.

Answer (score 17):

Not possible according to [this section](http:////docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) of the docs:

Custom filters are just Python functions that take one or two arguments:

- The value of the variable (input) --
  not necessarily a string.
- The value of the argument -- this can have a
  default value, or be left out altogether.

Comment: Van Gale's approach will work if you're using hard-coded strings.  Django ticket [https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1199] supports multiple arguments in a custom filter and a patch has been accepted.

Answer (score 3):

This feature has been marked as WONTFIX in 2013 Django's Trac: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1199

Comment: That ticket was closed as WONTFIX last year (2013), their developer suggest using a custom tag if need multiple arguments.

Answer (score 3):

**<my-site>/globaltags/replace.py**

```
from django.template import Library

import re

register = Library()

def search(value, search):
    return re.sub(search, '#f4x@SgXXmS', value)

def replace(value, replace):
    return re.sub('#f4x@SgXXmS', replace, value)

register.filter(search)
register.filter(replace)
```

**In the template:**

```
{{ "saniel"|search:"s"|replace:"d" }}
```

Comment: Would be nice if you explained `#f4x@SgXXmS` bit?

Comment: just a random string used as a placeholder. I've picked this string because I believed it won't be part of the input string. If for example I've used "{}" instead of '#f4x@SgXXmS' {{ "use {}  instead off []"|search:"off"|replace:"of" }} would return: "use of instead of []" and not the expected result: "use {} instead of []"

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Might be nice to declare it as `SUBSTRING_THAT_NEVER_OCCURS` thought.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use the separator `,` to pass multiple values to `replace` filter, then use the values by spliting with [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) as shown below. *You can and should use other separator which values don't have:

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def replace(value, args):
    cherche, remplacement = args.split(',')
    return value.replace(cherche, remplacement)
```

```
{{ "2023-06-23"|replace:"-,/" }} {% 2023/06/23 %}
                  {% Here ↑ %}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just simply do this:

```
{% assign find_total_issued = dailysalesreport | find: "TotalIssued":"13" %}

public static List<object> Find(object collection, string column, string value)
```

And it will reach the destination as the abstraction of the function is `sjare`.

Answer (score -2):

Heres a bad idea but works:

```
{{ xml|input_by_xpath:"{'type':'radio','xpath':'//result/value'}" }}
```

and

```
@register.filter
def input_by_xpath(device, args): 
    args = eval(args)
    ...
    result = "<input type=\"%s\" value=\"%s\" name=\"%s\"/>"%(args['type'],value,args['xpath'])
    return mark_safe(result)
```

Comment: Little warning : eval could add a security breach.
You should use json.loads instead.