# DJango Template - Custom template tags pass 2 variables

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I need to do something like this:

```
{% for team in association|get_teams_by_category_gender:category,gender %}
```

But django doesnt allow 2 arguments... How can I do that?

Basically, I need the filter to return a list of objects so I can loop through it and I will filter teams by category and gender.

Thanks,
Ara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ,

It is possible and fairly simple.

Django only allows one argument to your filter, but there's no reason you can't put all your arguments into a single string using a comma to separate them.

So for example, if you want a filter that checks if variable X is in the list [1,2,3,4] you will want a template filter that looks like this:

{% if X|is_in:"1,2,3,4" %}
Now we can create your templatetag like this:

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

def is_in(var, args):
    if args is None:
        return False
    arg_list = [arg.strip() for arg in args.split(',')]
    return var in arg_list

register.filter(is_in)
```

[How do I add multiple arguments to my custom template filter in a django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420703/how-do-i-add-multiple-arguments-to-my-custom-template-filter-in-a-django-templat)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. The problem with doing "category,gender" it will take the string category. But I want it take the object category....

Comment: @AraSivaneswaran Django only allows one argument to your filter, So you need to send the gender value and category value as a string, and this string handles the your templatetag method using `split(',')`.

Comment: And write your own logic.