# Django splitting a textfield using template tags

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I know that I can use **{{value|truncatewords:x}}** to truncate a textfield after a given number of words. Is it possible to use the truncated part afterwords if I want to sandwich something in between the text? Like using a string in python if I were to give

```
>>>string[:2]
>>>something in between
>>>string[2:]
```

but using template tags because I am iterating through a for loop and cannot pass it through my views?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) here.

Here's a simple example based on [`truncatewords()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/868ff4e37c1e4cfaf7283496c24f6e711ad66005/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L295) filter implementation:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from django.utils.text import Truncator

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
@stringfilter
def sandwich(value, args):
    length, cutlet = args.split(',')
    length = int(length)
    truncated_value = Truncator(value).words(length, truncate='')
    return ' '.join([truncated_value, cutlet, value[len(truncated_value):].strip()])
```

Example output:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> template = Template('{% load filters %}{{ value|sandwich:"2,magic" }}')
>>> context = Context({'value': 'What a wonderful world!'})
>>> template.render(context)
u'What a magic wonderful world!'
```

Note that Django doesn't allow multiple arguments to be passed in the template filter - that's why they are passed as a comma-separated string and then parsed. See more about the idea here: [How do I add multiple arguments to my custom template filter in a django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420703/how-do-i-add-multiple-arguments-to-my-custom-template-filter-in-a-django-templat)

Also, you would probably need to catch possible exceptions in case only one argument passed in the string, the `length` value cannot be converted to `int` etc.