# Django TemplateSyntaxError Could not parse the remainder

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Why can't I type this in a Django template?

```
data|customTag:variable,forloop.parentloop.counter
```

I just want to be able to pass three or more arguments into a filter

pretend there are already for loop and the variable/filter have been defined elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible since [django template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) accept only one argument *by definition*:

> Custom filters are just Python functions that take one or two
>   arguments:
>
> - The value of the variable (input) – not necessarily a string.
> - The
>     value of the argument – this can have a default value, or be left out
>     altogether.

There is a workaround suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423060/771848) that might work for your use case.

Another possible solution would be to split your tag with 2 input arguments into two tags with a single one and chain them in the template. It depends on the logic you have in the filter, but can be an option.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `customTag` is a *filter*, not a template tag.

[According to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), Django template filters only take the input (in your case `data`), and one optional argument. You are getting the error because you are trying to pass more than one argument, which is not possible.

You could write a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) instead. The syntax in your template would be:

```
{% customTag data variable forloop.parentloop.counter %}
```

Comment: I've decided to use this route. how would I actually pass in the context of data? because right now it just sends the string 'data'. and {{data}} just passes '{{data}}'

Comment: This is completely useless if I can't figure out how to pass in a variable... I tried reading the source code at defaulttags.py and I can't figure it out

Comment: If you use the [`simple_tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) decorator it should take care of this for you. Otherwise, you can fetch the variable out the `context`.