# Django template, send two arguments to template tag?

Tags: python, django, templates

Can anyone tell me if its possible to send multiple variables from field names to a template tag?

this question [How do I add multiple arguments to my custom template filter in a django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420703/how-do-i-add-multiple-arguments-to-my-custom-template-filter-in-a-django-templat) is almost there, but i dont know how to send my two field names as a string.

my template:

```
    <th>{{ item.cost_per_month|remaining_cost:item.install_date + ',' + item.contract_length }}</th>
```

the above didnt work

my template tags:

```
@register.filter('contract_remainder')
def contract_remainder(install_date, contract_term):
    months = 0
    now = datetime.now().date()
    end_date = install_date + relativedelta(years=contract_term)

    while True:
        mdays = monthrange(now.year, now.month)[1]
        now += timedelta(days=mdays)
        if now <= end_date:
            months += 1
        else:
            break
    return months    

@register.filter('remaining_cost')
def remaining_cost(cost_per_month, remainder_vars):
    dates = remainder_vars.split(',')
    cost = contract_remainder(dates[0], dates[1]) * cost_per_month
    return cost
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From my point of view it looks easier to use a simple tag instead of a template filter so you can call it without needing to send a string.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags

Your template would be just:

```html
{% load remaining_cost %}
{# Don't forget to load the template tag as above #}

<th>{% remaining_cost item.cost_per_month item.install_date item.comtract_length %}</th>
```

and the template tag would be:

```
@register.simple_tag
def remaining_cost(cost_per_month, install_date, contract_length):
    cost = contract_remainder(install_date, contract_length) * cost_per_month
    return cost
```

Comment: wasnt aware of simple tag! however im getting an error when i use simple tag... "
Invalid block tag on line 206: 'remaining_cost', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

206    <td>{% remaining_cost item.cost_per_month item.install_date item.comtract_length %}</td>

Comment: Sorry I forgot. You have to put {% load <tag name> %}

Comment: At the top of your template

Comment: hi, yup that already was already added, i have a few other filters loaded on the same .py

Comment: I'm not able to point at the problem. could you update your code in your question so I can see what it looks like now ?

Comment: you should load the name of python file containing your filters without the `.py` extension. For example {% load <filename> %}

Comment: I got error as well when I have tried to implement but @thierno comment was helpful. The above example is a bit ambiguous what you should load. So if you have a file with multiple template tags you should load the file name instead of the name of the tag({% load my_filters_file %})