# Filter 2D list with template tag in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, templatetags

I'm trying to write a template tag that will filter a 2D list.

This is my template tag:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def index_two(seq, position1, position2):
    return seq[position1][position2]
```

This is my list that I'm passing to my template:

```
summary = [[50, 0, 0], [50, 100, 100]]
```

I'm trying to reference the first element of the first list in summary, like so:

```
{{summary|index_two:0 0}}
```

However, I received a template syntax error: index_two requires 3 arguments, 2 provided.

I've tried to adjust my template tag to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021159/django-template-send-two-arguments-to-template-tag), but I can't get it to work for me.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: According to the documentation, a template filter can take at most two parameters. But you can for example wrap the two in a string, and thus pass the two parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Django template filter takes at most two parameters (the one that is passed with the "pipe" (`|`) character, and an optional extra one, like is specified in the [documentation [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

> Custom filters are just Python functions that take one or two
>   arguments:
>
> 1. The value of the variable (input) – not necessarily a string.
> 2. The value of the argument – this can have a default value, or be left out altogether

But we can make the component more reusable, and thus obtain an single element each time, like:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def index(seq, position):
    return seq[position]
```

Then we can write it like:

```
{{ summary|index:0|index:0 }}
```

So now we can use `index` to obtain an element of a list, and by chaining, we can dive deeper into the list. We thus make the function more reusable.

This technique is somewhat related to *currying* in functional programming where functions always take exactly one parameter.

Alternative, you can use some sort of format that can be decoded, like for example a string containing comma-separated values:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def index_two(seq, positions):
    p1, p2 = map(int, positions.split(','))
    return seq[p1][p2]
```

and then use it like:

```
{{ summary|index_two:'0,0' }}
```

But personally I find this less elegant, and will probably cause more trouble, since it requires a well defined format, and it is always possible that it fails for some corner cases.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is inspired by Willem Van Onsem's comment:

Template tag:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def index(seq, pos):
    position1 = int(pos.split(" ")[0])
    position2 = int(pos.split(" ")[1])

return seq[position1][position2]
```

Template:

```
{{summary|index:'0 0'}
```

Comment: Lol, we came up with the same edit, at the same time :)