# how to get date after some specific number of days from given date in django template

Tags: django, python-3.x, date, django-templates

I am new in django. I want to get date after some specific number of days or number of weeks in html template file.

my template file code:

```
{% for factors in c.factor %}
    {% for factor_details in factors.factor_values %}
         {{factor_details.id}}
         {{factor_details.factor_value}}
            # here this is given date {{order_detail.oderdate}} and this is number of days and weeks {{factor_details.factor_value}}.

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

order Model :

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_no = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True) # AB31DE3
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(Addresses, related_name="shipping_address",null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(Addresses, related_name="billing_address",null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shipping_total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=65, decimal_places=2)
    totalamount = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=65, decimal_places=2)
    stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    oderdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

factor Model :

```
class ProductPriceFactor(models.Model):
    factor_value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

orderdate and factor_values from different model so orderdate from `order` model and factor_value from `ProductPriceFactor` model. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `factor_details` is coming from a Model. Then you can add a method in model and render the value in template. For example:

```
import datetime

class FactorDetail(models.Model):
   ...

   def date_after_some_days(self):
       return self.oderdate + datetime.timedelta(days=self.factor_value)
```

Then render the value in template:

```
{% for factor_details in factors.factor_values %}
     {{ factor_details.id }}
     {{ factor_details.factor_value }}
     {{ factor_details.date_after_some_days }}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Update

above solution won't work here because you don't have any relation between orderdate and factor_value. Instead, you can create a [**`template filter`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

```
# template filter tag

@register.filter(name='factor_date')
def factor_date(value, arg):

    return value + datetime.timedelta(days=int(arg))
```

And update the template with filter:

```
{% for factor_details in factors.factor_values %}
     {{ factor_details.id }}
     {{ factor_details.factor_value }}
     {{ orderdetail.oderdate|factor_date:factor_details.factor_value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: oderdate and factor_value both are from different table. @ruddra

Comment: can you share the models please?

Comment: see i share models in my question

Comment: It is mentioned in documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout

Comment: can we pass multiple arguments in `{{ orderdetail.oderdate|factor_date:factor_details.factor_value }}` ?

Comment: um, you can't send multiple arguments, but you can send a list. More details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/423060/2696165

Comment: i follow that link but it's not working for me@ruddra

Comment: Um, can you please ask a new question with what you have tried :) ? Because its hard to tell what is going on or why the code isn't working without seeing the actual code.